# Extract part of the string

Tags: c#, string

I have thousands of lines of string type data, and what I need is to extract the string after `AS`. For example this line:

```
CASE  END AS NoHearing,
```

What I want would be `NoHearing,`

This line:

```
 CASE 19083812 END AS NoRequset
```

What I need would be `NoRequset`

So far I have tried couple ways of doing it but no success. Can't use `.split` because `AS` is not `Char` type.

Comment: You can split by strings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Is it safe to assume that "AS" only appears once (and must happen, no rows without)? If not, what about "END AS"?

Comment: Split by the whitespace `' '` and take the `.Last()` result.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Your method worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

If this will be the only way that AS appears in the string:

```
noRequestString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("AS") + 3);
```

Comment: Thanks @juharr - appreciate the correction as I get used to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex I extract all between the AS and a comma:

```
string data = @"
CASE  END AS NoHearing,
CASE 19083812 END AS NoRequset
";

var items = Regex.Matches(data, @"(?:AS\s+)(?<AsWhat>[^\s,]+)")
                 .OfType<Match>()
                 .Select (mt => mt.Groups["AsWhat"])
                 .ToList();


Console.WriteLine (string.Join(" ", items)); // NoHearing NoRequset
```